# PHP return Database row details by user id

Tags: php

I have my own cms that built ,

I used on the userid AUTO_INCREMENT
My db users look like this till now:

```
    userid | username | fname | email | password | salt | timastamp
   ----------------------------------------------------------------
      1       test      b.k   a@a.com  dsfsd...  df...    11334544
      2       test1     s.k   a@a.com  dsfsd...  df...    11334544
```

Here i removed the AUTO_INCREMENT and change the userid row from int to varchar
And now i have  this :

```
    userid | username | fname | email | password | salt | timastamp
   ----------------------------------------------------------------
    4CsdGf     test      b.k   a@a.com  dsfsd...  df...    11334544
    5C6dd3     test1     s.k   a@a.com  dsfsd...  df...    11334544
```

I have removed from the userid Structure the AUTO_INCREMENT and using the following script to gerenate new id for every new register account:

```
function genID()
{
$seed = str_split('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' 
.'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' 
.'0123456789' ); // and any other characters
shuffle($seed); // probably optional since array_is randomized; this may be redundant
$rand = '' ;
foreach (array_rand($seed, 5) as $k) $rand .= $seed[$k];

return $rand;

}
```

Till now i used this function to get all user data by userid:

```
 function get_user_data_by_userid($one_page_id)
{
    $one_page_id = $this->db_clean($one_page_id);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = ".$one_page_id;

    //die($query);
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

    $result = mysql_query($query, $this->connection);

    if(!$result) //ERROR IN YOUR SQL QUERY
    return false;

    if(mysql_num_rows($result)==0) //NO ROWS IN TABLE pages
    return false;

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);

    return $row;
}

 $user_data = $func->get_user_data_by_userid($user_id);

 //example of take specific data :

  echo $user_data['userid'];
```

But its wont working anymore , its not get the data by the userid since i have change the user id from AUTO_INCREMENT to my own Generate ID'S function , Any idea what wrong ?

I have did die to query at $func->get_user_data_by_userid() and its working perfect :

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = 63FWo
```

but its not retrive the data from that id why any idea?
Thanks allot.

**UPDATE:**
The fix :\ :

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = '$one_page_id'";
```

forgot quotes..

Comment: This calls for basic debugging. Does your query work out? What does `mysql_error()` say? (You need to wrap `63FWo` in quotes, that is likely to be breaking the query)

Comment: Hi , its says Warning: mysql_error() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given

Comment: A simple `echo mysql_error()` will not output that warning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change to this.

```
  SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = '63FWo';
```

Comment: Ok , my mistake i forgot to put this like u sayed : $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = '$one_page_id'"; in quotes and now working :) thanks , i will accept answer more 9 minutes StackOverFlaw limit 10 minutes before accept

Answer (score 0):

**Use Apostrophe**

when you try to select int values

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = 1";
```

when you try to select string values

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = '63FWo'";
```